# How can you get and update tags for a given VM using vCenter APIs?

Tags: vmware, vcenter

I am able to get a list of all VMs and then get each VM property, but the VM property endpoint does not show the tags assigned.

Which endpoints should I be using?

I am getting all VMs with

```
/api/vcenter/vm
```

and then

```
api/vcenter/vm/{VM}
```

to get the property for each VM.

I saw this somewhere on the internet `api/vcenter/vm/{vm}/tags` but its giving me an unauthorized error.